# DAX calculations or measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to this community and I seek guidance and assistance to those who are experts in this particular field.

I have a table where I need to know how many ideal customers we have by these requirements:

X & Y Services(Services Column) - Should be both
TRUE(Boolean Column) - this will state that they really offer the Services(X &Y)
Description(Description Column) - Either of the 3 specific description

Roadblocks - when I filter the services and boolean column, the description column will be empty. Same goes with description column, services column will be empty.

In order to know how many Ideal customer, need to pass the requirements/criteria.

Please advise, thank you!

Created a Dax. No result.

Comment: Add some sample data in copiable format together with expected results.

Comment: @JosWoolley, how can I upload or attached a file?

Comment: @JosWoolley, I posted another comment where there is my expected result.

Comment: Thanks, but that appears to be a picture, not copiable data. Most potential responders aren't prepared to recreate your dataset by manually typing in data from a picture.